# When TWAP is used in uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, defi

TWAP is the average price of an asset in a given time period. However, I am confused about when it is used.

When I use the Uniswap app to swap tokens, I do not pass any time variables. How does Uniswap determine the price of the tokens then?

Comment: the oracle is there only to prevent price manipulation by some attacker that might borrow money at the lending pool, but the price is determined by the demand "curve" as described in the whitepaper. you don't have to provide any time because it is tracked internally by the contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniswap pools can be used as oracles, for instance by other smart contracts. Since the spot price of a pool can easily be manipulated, such an oracles should use something like time-weighted average price (TWAP) to make the manipulation more difficult.

Uniswap v3 pools include some functionality for getting something like TWAP, specifically, v3 pools accumulate the time-weighted average tick, in other words, the time-weighted average of the *log* price (i.e. the geometric mean of prices). Uniswap itself does not make use of these accumulators in any way, they are meant solely for external uses. The spot price in a Uniswap pool is determined by the pool's bonding curve - a deterministic function from the amounts of assets in the pool and other parameters.

Comment: what kind of external uses?